# Display error message if paperclip have no attachment sent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, paperclip-validation

I have set up paperclip to my app successfully and everything works except one thing. When I submit the form (the one with paperclip attachment) I get error saying: `param is missing or the value is empty: user` and error is highlighting this part of my code:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:photo)
```

So, since I submit the form empty, rails things :photo is empty and it is right though. I did some research, people use this to make it work:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:photo) if params[:photo]
```

But, when I use if statement I get this error:

```
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

and error highlights the if statement (first line) in this code:

```
if @profile.update_attributes(photo_parameter)
  flash[:notice] = 'Your profile photo has been updated successfully'
  redirect_to request.referer
else
```

Beside that, I also tried adding this to my model, but still doesn't work

```
validates_attachment_presence :photo
```

I am very confused. I thought you guys may have had the same problem. Because I am just simply trying show error message if there is no attachment submitted.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you defined `photo_parameter` as a private method in your controller. Can you update your question with it.

Comment: @cyonder, have you got it working?